# How do I change the Views (Entity Reference) filter via AJAX?

Tags: views, 8, entities, hooks, ajax

I have an entity form that allows an admin to select a content type (checkbox) and an autocomplete field that is tapped into a VIEWS Entity Reference (via the Reference Method).

Goal: What I would like is to have the views entity reference filter dynamically change based off the end-user selection.  Contextual Filters would have worked but I think Filters is better because of the multiple selection.

So far I have a view with entity reference and it is pulling the correct data for content 1-4.  When I use the autocomplete it does what it's supposed to. I think the next step is to use AJAX to change how the autocomplete pulls from the view by changing the FILTER.

Can you help me figure out how I can change the views filter via AJAX/JS?

[image: An example of what I am talking about]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question in hopes this ccan help someone.  However I am welcome to hear other options :)

What I ended up doing was attach a javascript that updates the autocomplete's path.  Meaning when a user clicks on the checkbox it updates the input box for the autocomplete's attribute. The attribute called `data-autocomplete-path`.  I appended a query string without messing with the functionality of it.  This extra value gets sent to `hook_views_pre_view`.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The core issue for this is [Add AJAX support to fields using Dynamic Views Arguments via Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3073970), but at the time of this writing the only option available without custom coding is [Business Rules' dependent field functionality](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/business-rules/advanced-usage/dependent-field).

However, there are still unresolved problems with multi-valued fields.  See [Multi-valued dependent child fields are not saved](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules/issues/3014031) for more information.